# SQL package call in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a database handler which is called with a SQL-String which calls the package.

**Database Handler Call**

```
private List<ProductionPending> GetPendingProductionDeployments()
{
    List<ProductionPending> list = null;
    sqlStr = "ADM_PORTAL_REP.p_PendingProductionDeployments;";
    DataTable dt = dbhandler.ExecuteQuery(sqlStr, "2016-04");
    return dt;
}
```

Then in the  Database Handler following error happens on following line:`adp.Fill(dt);`

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 57: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "," when expecting one of the following:
>
> . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4
>   likec as between || indicator multiset member    submultiset

**Database Handler**

```
    public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string p_sqlStr, string p_releaseId)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
        {
            using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(p_sqlStr, conn))
            {
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                OracleParameter outRefCursor = objCommand.Parameters.Add("pc_recordset", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
                outRefCursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                OracleParameter releaseId = objCommand.Parameters.Add("ps_releaseid", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                releaseId.Value = p_releaseId;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
                conn.Open();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now I guess the Error is caused  by the SQL i send as a parameter (the package call: `"ADM_PORTAL_REP.p_PendingProductionDeployments;"`), because when I call the package in SQL Developer and not in Visual Studio, the Package executes and works well. That error only happens in Visual Studio.

**SQL Package**

```
   PROCEDURE p_PendingProductionDeployments (pc_recordset IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, ps_releaseid VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
    OPEN pc_recordset FOR
        SELECT NVL(NULL, 0) ID,
            RELEASEID releaseId,
            RFC RFCNumber,
            DEVELOPER developerInitials,
            FILENAME fileName,
            VERSION fileVersion,
            NVL(RFD, 0) RFDNumber,
            NVL(DEPLOYDATE, '1-Jan-0001') desiredDeploymentDate,
            NVL(NULL, '1-Jan-1900') deploymentDate,
            NOTES,
            DETAIL_NOTES detailNotes, 
            'N' approvedInd, 
            DATE_REQUESTED dateRequested 
        FROM ADM_PROD_DEPLOYMENTS_V 
      WHERE RELEASEID = ps_releaseid;
    END p_PendingProductionDeployments;
```

[Screenshot: Error In Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR3jB.png)

Comment: Have you tried leaving away the semicolon?

Comment: wow, sorry totally oversaw that, Yes thats the cause of the error, post this as answer i will accept it!

Comment: A comprehensive question for a simple problem - better than the other way around

Comment: OT: about `if (dt != null)`: you don't need that check as you have just created a fresh `dt`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to leave away the semicolon in your query.

```
sqlStr = "ADM_PORTAL_REP.p_PendingProductionDeployments";
```